# Check boxes Value Manipulation

Tags: php, mysql, html

Below are my static check boxes with values.

What I need is when user Checks any of the check boxes and then click submit I need the checked chec kboxes values in php further i want to place them in mysql query like this

```
select * from table where "all check boxes values"
```

My search in mysql will be based on all the checked values

```
echo "<table border='0'>";
echo "<p>Make a Selection to view details</p>";
echo "<tr><th>Scheme Type</th><th>Scehme Sector</th><th>Area</th><th>Year</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='ADP' /> District ADP <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='cmd'/> CM Directives <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='tkpp'/> Tameer KPK Program <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='tbcess' /> Tobacco Cess</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='wss' /> Water Supply & Sanitation <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='road'/> Roads <br/>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='ccb'/> CCB <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='health'/> Health <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='education'/> Education <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='others' /> Others</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='pk77'/> PK-77 <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='pk78'/> PK-78 <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='pk79' /> PK-79 </td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='1112'/> 2011-12 <br/>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkSkills' value='1011'/> 2010-11 </td></tr>";
echo  "<tr><td colspan='4' align='right' style='background-color:white;'><input type='submit' name='devsub' value='Submit' /></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Regards

Comment: `print_r($_POST['chkSkills'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `name = chkSkills[]` for each checkbox
and retrieve via `$_POST['chkSkills']`

Than just do this

```
foreach($_POST['chkSkills'] as $key => $value){
MYSQL_QUERY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use name chkSkills[] and then

use  in php

```
if(count($_POST['chkSkills']) > 0)
{
     $checkboxes=implode(',',$_POST['chkSkills']);
}
```

then
   make query

select * from table where cloumnname in($checkboxes)

Comment: can i put multiple column names in select query after where

Comment: select * from table where cloumnname in($checkboxes) and cloumnname2 in($checkboxes)